# Why are Trump's handwritten notes being focused on in the news?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, media, trump-impeachment

The news articles appear to focus strongly on those notes that say "I WANT NO QUID PRO QUO" and the like.  I appear to be missing the relevance of this, since the news seems to be focusing on the fact that these notes exist.  They appear to be fairly obvious - talking points for speaking with the media with the same message that's been said from the beginning.  Is there more to those notes that I'm missing, or is it perhaps a need to fill stories with what is most publicly interesting at the moment?

Comment: Are those notes really from him? I thought it was a photoshoped image

Comment: @QuoraFeans I thought so too, but they do indeed seem to be his real speech notes

Answer (score 34, accepted):

What the note says, how it is written, and specifically, that the Ukrainian president's name is misspelled in the note tell us a lot about the thought processes of Donald Trump in making his statement.

The note itself shows us what Trump thought most important in what he said.

> The notes say so much, less about what Trump said or Sondland
>   testified — the ambassador stated explicitly before Congress that
>   Ukraine had been subject to a quid pro quo — than how he views himself
>   in this moment. “THE FINAL WORD FROM THE PRES OF THE U.S.” sounds more
>   like a dictum from the great and powerful Oz than from a
>   democratically elected leader. The misspelling of Ukraine president
>   Volodymyr Zelensky's name betrays a casual disregard for even the most
>   basic facts of the matter. And the giant lettering supports the
>   operating theory that Trump refuses to wear glasses that he sorely
>   needs.
>
> The public would have none of that additional insight without Wilson’s
>   photograph.

https://www.wired.com/story/trump-notes-photographer/

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101342/discussion-on-answer-by-geoffatkins-why-are-trumps-handwritten-notes-being-focu).

Comment: Please respect the move to chat.

Answer (score -7):

> Why are Trump's handwritten notes being focused on in the news?

It's not just Trump's notes that are focused on. There have been similar cases in the past, e.g. [Bolton accidentally showing notes](https://eu.usatoday.com/story/news/world/2019/01/28/john-bolton-notepad-troops-colombia-venezuela-military-intervention/2705957002/) *(The picture is an AP photo, so I'm not sure I can embed it here - see the article)*.

There have been more cases, but I don't recall by whom and searching for them is hard.

Usually, those notes contain confidential material. That's why the press zooms in on every paper carried by a politician and his or her aides: **there is news to be found**! It is usually an unexperienced aide that makes this rookie mistake; Experienced politicians have developed the habit to always cover their notes. In that sense, Bolton's mistake is the outlier.

> Is there more to those notes that I'm missing, [..]

Given the frenzy by the press trying to capture notes, it is well possible that Trump wanted those notes to be visible and distributed widely. In other words: **Trump lured the press into spreading Trump's message**.

Comment: Interesting theory, but in this case why does he wants everyone to know that "he wants nothing" so much? If this was a cunning plan, wouldn't he have prepared a smarter message?

Comment: It’s a good answer up to the speculation that this was some sort of masterful 4-D chess move.

Comment: Is there any evidence that this was Trumps plan all along?